# Is MongoDB suitable for loading random records?

Tags: mongodb

Our application stores records with shorter texts (strings of 100-1000 characters).
It provides search for most similar records to a given query text.
We use Lucene for indexing the texts.
Complete records are stored in database.
Each record belongs to exactly one domain, there are now more than 1000 domains. Number of domains is unlimited but grows slowly.
Records are being added continuously to all domains (not uniformly).

We employed Mysql as database, where each domain had its own table.
Now we try to migrate to MongoDB because of scaling out. All records are stored in single collection there, domain is an attribute of the record.
Ids are still obtained from Lucene search. 
But we observe inferior performance of loading records from MongDB in comparision to the solution with Mysql.
I suspect the "Memory Mapped Storage Engine" of MongoDB is the reason.
Each search can return "random record". There are often more searches from one domain in succession. Records from one domain are not stored in one place in the collection.
This may cause many page faults.

Is my explanation right? Is MongoDB suitable for such record loading? What could improve the performance?
MongoDB server and the application are running on Linux.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: One does a record look like? How are you importing the data? What are the specs of your Linux server?

Comment: A record has text and some additional properties (timestamp, created_by,...). Records are continuously added by users - single insert or mass insert. Mass insert is sequence of single inserts actually. Record is inserted to mongoDB and the text with id to Lucene index. Linux Ubuntu 10.04 8GB RAM, 2 CPU cores (for example Amazon EC2 large instance).

Comment: It is not suitable to store whole record to Lucene. In addition records with almost same text from one domain are indexed  as one document in indexer because of optimization.

Comment: OK, so I wasn't sure if it was a manual mongoimport - what driver is your application using? What version of Mongo? MongoDB is ideal for that type of data, it shouldn't be an issue. What is pointing to inferior performance? How many mongod instances are you running? I presume your working set fits within RAM. Remember that if you've a write-heavy environment, you need to look at scaling your writes and this is where you need to look at sharding (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/?highlight=sharding) and then the key decision is picking the correct shard key.

Comment: Thank you. We use Java driver, Mongo 2.0.5. Indexes and working set should fit within RAM. But the working set can change rapidly, and for this reason I worry there may be many page faults in virtual memory when database size is many times bigger than RAM size. I see the sharding as a solution to decrease database size to RAM size ratio. We have only a rough comparison, we will test the speed more.

Comment: Yep, indeed that is why some folk use sharding. BTW, you can use the Mongo Monitoring Service for free to help monitor your implementation  -https://www.10gen.com/mongodb-monitoring-service. It's great for an overview but also for drilling down. Should I change my comment above to an answer?

Comment: Thanks, yes please change to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's important that your working set (data and indexes) fits within RAM. There are tonnes of posts/blogs on this so just google "MongoDB working set" but as you know, access from RAM rather paging to disk is quicker.

Remember that if you've a write-heavy environment, you need to look at scaling your writes and this is where you need to look at [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/?highlight=sharding) and then the key decision is picking the correct shard key. This is very important and it is immutable so give it lots of thought :) Here's a good [doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key) on picking the key.

One other thing, regarding the Java driver, use [version 2.8](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10006&version=10980), there've been quite a few changes, including some that are [sharding-related](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-525).

Finally,  you can use the [Mongo Monitoring Service](http://10gen.com/mongodb-monitoring-service) for free to help monitor your implementation. It's great for an overview but also for drilling down.